# What are the subsets of adverbs?

Tags: adverbs

Adverb is a part of speech, so there is a clear distinction between other part of speeches. But what about the inner structure of this category?
So far, i happened to know that one subset of adverbs is called distributive adverbs, i do not know the definition, but words like: few, some, all, none belong to it.

Comment: Few, some, all, none - these words are not adverbs, they are pronouns, namely the indefinite pronouns.

Comment: Unfortunately the adverb word class is incredibly inconsistently defined.

Comment: Hey you, out there in the cold getting lonely getting old, can you feel me? Hey you, standing in the aisles with itchy feet and fading smiles, can you feel me? Hey you, don't help them to bury the light, don't give in without a fight. Hey you, out there on your own sitting naked by the phone, would you touch me? Hey you, with you ear against the wall waiting for someone to call out, would you touch me? Hey you, would you help me to carry the stone? Open your heart, I'm coming home.

Answer (score 1):

The Cambridge Dictionary site [classifies the adverbs](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/adverbs-types) into:

- Time adverbs: now, today, still
- Place adverbs: nearby, upstairs, here
- Manner adverbs: quickly, badly, slowly
- Degree adverbs: absolutely, enough, perfectly
- Focusing adverbs: especially, just, mainly
- Evaluative adverbs (surprisingly) and viewpoint adverbs (personally)
- Linking adverbs: then, however, consequently